# How to use Kotlin with React Native in Android Studio?

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

I want to make an android app using Kotlin for the back end and Android Studio. For the front end, I understand that React Native would be a powerful choice, however I cannot figure out how to add ReactN to my Kotlin project.

I also tried creating a project in ReactN and then adding Kotlin: installed nodejs, npm and create-react-native-app, made the project. Then I tried opening it in Android Studio, but I wasn't getting any options to actually compile and run the project. So another question would be: can you work on ReactN projects in Android Studio or not?

If you could give me some resources on how exactly to do this, or if you can walk me through it step by step, it would be very helpful. I want to mention that I've never developed for Android or Web before (I'm mentioning about Web because I cannot rely on any Reactjs knowledge from Web dev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native is whole framework, for front and back end, and have nothing to do with Kotlin (well, some Kotlin snippets may be integrated into RN app, thats all). RN projects are in fact multiplatform apps and Kotlin is used for writing pure Android apps, so this isn't a front/back end separation in here, these are just different approaches to development. Mixing both, while possible, makes no sense in most cases

Comment: Oh, I understand. And if I want to go with Kotlin, what can I use for designing? There is XML, but is it enough, or are there tools that can make my life easier?

Comment: XML covers everything, but may be hard for beginner to write whole layout. luckily lastly Android Studio got update with visual support for writing XMLs, so it may be easier for newbies :) get familiar with `ConstraintLayout`, `RecyclerView` and `CooridnatorLayout`, pretty powerful ones and very useful. Also consider using Jetpack Compose and Material Components libs, check them out. good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll check them out!